# Print functionality implementation in website

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, printing, web

Currently I am implementing print functionality in a website. Can any one tell me what are the best practice to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

You should use CSS and write a print Stylesheet. This will be automatically used, if the user clicks on print.

Comment: I am showing a printer friendly version by hiding the unwanted items(like: adds,menu etc.)  using jquery?Is it a right approach?

Comment: I think it would be less work to just use CSS and set `display=none` where you don't want to show blocks.

Comment: @ANP — no, that's the long, complicated, more error prone, less reliable approach. Just use a print stylesheet as suggested in this answer. No need to go near JavaScript.

Comment: To supplement this answer: the way you create the print stylesheet (or incorporate print information in your existing style sheet) is with **media selectors**: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be *absolutely sure* of how something will print for the user you'll have to create a PDF with a library such as [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/).  Using stylesheets with the print attribute is an excellent idea, but you can't guarantee it will print all on one page, correct orientation etc.

Comment: This is a great way to deal with printing - But in many cases a overkill